# Nginx rewrite all when file doesn't exist except if in directory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the following part of code in my nginx:

```
server {    
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
include snippets/ssl-renmind.net.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

...



    rewrite ^/manage/GO/(.+)$ /gatherOpinionAdmin/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/manage/CT/(.+)$ /couponTracksAdmin/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/manage/CH/(.+)$ /contestHeroAdmin/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/manage/DC/(.+)$ /distributeContentAdmin/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/manage/PD/(.+)$ /productsAdmin/$1 last;
    rewrite ^/manage/PP/(.+)$ /pitchPageAdmin/$1 last;

    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/GO/(.+)$ /gatherOpinionUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/CH/(.+)$ /contestHeroUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/CT/(.+)$ /couponTracksUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/DC/(.+)$ /distributeContentUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/PD/(.+)$ /productsUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;


    if (!-e $request_filename){
        #rewrite ^/([^/]+)(.*+)$ /genUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
}
}
```

I'm trying to add this:

```
    location /webmin/ {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:10000/;
        proxy_redirect https://$host:10000/ /webmin/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

Which works only if I take out the last rewrite above that rewrites all non existing files (currently commented out).  How would I accomplish by perhaps skipping all rewrites if the it's location /webmin/.  /webmin/ doesn't actually exist as a file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following setup:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)(.*+)$ /genUser/$2?currentFolder=$1 last;
    }
}

location /webmin {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:10000/;
    proxy_redirect https://$host:10000/ /webmin/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

The important part here is to add the `location /` block, so that nginx will use the `location` lookup properly.

It also might be possible to get rid of the `if` statement, [which is always preferred](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok every time finally ask for help I figure stuff out.

Putting this in:
if ($request_uri ~ (/webmin)){
           break;
    }

fixes the issue.